# How to convert map value into list?

Tags: java, jsp

I am having a Map:

```
Map<Object,List<Object>> values=new HashMap<Object,List<Object>>();
```

and List is:

```
List<Object> ls=new ArrayList<Object>();
```

How to convert the Map(values) into List(ls) and i have to display list value iterator in jsp..

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a List of the Map entries:

```
List<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> list = 
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Key, Value>>(map.entrySet());
```

FYI, entries have a getKey() and a getValue() method.